# Prove that a conjugate of a subgroup is a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

> Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ and $a\in G$ fixed, then
> $$H^{a}=aHa^{-1}=\{aHa^{-1} \colon h\in H\}$$
> is a subgroup of $G$.

my attempt

**Identity**

$aha^{-1} \in H^a$

$aea^{-1} \in H^a\ \ \ \ $ Since $e ∈ H$

$aa^{-1} \in H^a$

Therefore $aa^{-1} = e ∈ H^{a}$

**Closed under the operation of $G$**

Let $p,q ∈ H^{a}$ and $x,y ∈ H$

$p = axa^{-1}$ q = $aya^{-1}$

as $H$ is a group

$x*y ∈ H$

$p*q = a(xy)a^{-1} ∈ H$

**Inverse**

let p ∈ $H^{a}$ and $x ∈ H$

$p = axa^{-1}$

$p^{-1} = ax^{-1}a^{-1}$

Then, $p^{-1} ∈ H^a$ for all $p ∈ H$

Comment: Shouldn't $a$ and $a^{-1}$ be switched in second last statement?

Comment: Overall this is reasonably correct.  However, it’s poor form to write $H^a = aea^{-1}$ because the LHS is a set and the RHS is an element.  Rather than forcing the equal sign to mean something it does not, it’s better to use simple, precise English: “$H^a$ contains $aea^{-1}$”.  Similarly, the $h$ and $H$ are mixed up in the definition of $H^a$.

Comment: You seem to be confused regarding sets versus individual elements. The statement "$H^{a}=aha^{-1}=\{aHa^{-1} \colon h\in H\}$" is quite wrong for that reason. It's easy to figure out what you were supposed to say here, but you didn't say it correctly, ending up with a meaningless statement. For example, $H^{a}$ is a set (being a subset of $G$), while $aha^{-1}$ is an individual element, so they can't possibly be equal to each other.

Comment: Wow, you ask a lot of homework questions! 35 homework questions within the last two months. I hope your instructors allow this, or else you might be in some trouble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You should write sentences and paragraphs, not just lists of equations.
2. Why is $pq = a(xy)a^{-1}$? Explain. (This is easy, so it will be a short explanation. But it should be explained in a class at this level.)
3. Don't let $x,y \in H$. Instead say: Let $p, q \in H^a$. Then there are $x,y \in H$ such that $p = axa^{-1}$ and $q = aya^{-1}$. Therefore...
4. Again, for "Inverse", don't say let $p \in H^a$ and $x \in H$. Instead, say: Let $p \in H^a$. Then there is an $x \in H$ such that $p = axa^{-1}$. Therefore...
5. Why is $p^{-1} = ax^{-1}a^{-1}$? Explain.
6. Why is $p^{-1} \in H^a$? Explain. (You have said $p^{-1} = ax^{-1}a^{-1}$. So? Explain why this implies $p^{-1} \in H^a$. Hint: $x^{-1} \in$...)

"Identity" is a mess. You wrote: $H^a = aha^{-1}$. No. No! $H^a$ is a subset of $G$. $aha^{-1}$ is a single element of $G$. They are not the same kind of thing: one is a set, the other is an element. They are not equal. Are you trying to say that $H^a$ is the set of $aha^{-1}$, for all $h \in H$? If that's what you want to say, then say that. Although I don't know why you would want to say that. If what you want to say is something else, then say *that* instead.

In the next line you write $H^a = aea^{-1}$ since $e \in H$. No!! Are you trying to say that $H^a$ includes the element $aea^{-1}$? There is a correct way to say that. You seem to know what that correct way is: you wrote $e \in H$. And indeed, you can write $aea^{-1} \in H^a$.

Well, I'm sorry to be critical of how you wrote this. You clearly understand the main mathematical ideas. I hope that you will write your proof more carefully.

Comment: I think you should be critical about the writing of a proof. Idea alone is not enough, one needs to express them clearly. We can't mind read, and we don't need to. This is very important that one should learn how to write a proof clearly. If the OP writes this proof in a test, she/he will not be awarded any marks for it. Writing is a part of the training. (+1) of course!!

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Let $H \leq G$

Let $H'= \{aHa^- \}$ be some congjugate Subgroup cnjugated by some $ a \in G$ where
$\{ah_1a^- , ah_2a^- .. \} \in H' $ for every $\{h_1 , h_2 ..\} \in H $

1. $(ah_1a^-)(ah_2a^-) = ah_1h_2a^- = ah_3a^- \in H'$. This proves closure
2. Associativity can be inhertied from group compsotion since they are all either subset or subgroup of the larger group $G$
3. By Conjuagation of $a$ with $e \in H$ , $aea^- \in H' \Rightarrow e \in H'$.
4. For some $\{h ,h^- \}\in H$ there is $ \{ aha^-,ah^-a^-\} \in H'$ . Direct compostion of these two elements in $H'$. we have $$(aha^-)(ah^-a^-) = e $$ 
   We have containment of inverse element in the group.

Answer (score 0):

Use subgroup criterion:

> $a 1 a^-1 = 1 \in H'$, so H' is not empty.

Say $\{h_1, h_2\} \in H$, so $\{a h_1 a^{-1}, a h_2 a^{-1}\} \in H'$. We show that $a h_1 a^{-1} (a h_2 a^{-1})^{-1} \in H'$:

> $a h_1 a^{-1} (a h_2 a^{-1})^{-1} = a h_1 a^{-1} a h_2^{-1}a^{-1} = a h_1 h_2^{-1}a^{-1} \in H'$.